# Blogger random number script and redirect not stop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying this code in blogger html -

```
<script>
var minNumber = 0; 
var maxNumber = 2; 
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1 - minNumber)) + minNumber;

alert(randomnumber); // (To catch error clearly)

if(randomnumber===0){

        document.write(&quot;<object data='http://test1.com/' height='100%' type='text/html' width='102%'/>&quot;);
   }


else if(randomnumber===1){

        document.write(&quot;<object data='http://test2.com/' height='100%' type='text/html' width='102%'/>&quot;);

}
else if(randomnumber===2){

        document.write(&quot;<object data='http://test3.com/' height='100%' type='text/html' width='102%'/>&quot;);

}
</script>
```

This code never stops on option 0 and 1 , It stops when randomnumber becomes 2(Last line number). 
looping pattern is like that , 0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,2-stopped (never stop until become last line option number)

I tried to stop it by break; and return; . But not working with them , not showing anything.

Please kindly help me . Thank you.

Comment: @ washington-guedes . Thank you for guide. But you are misunderstanding to me . I don't want to remove last number. My problem is script is looping with specified random numbers until it gets last number. 

Please test it with "   alert(randomnumber);  " . You can see clearly with it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry , I am not having problem with those random numbers and line of code. my problem is on if/else if statements, they are not stopped randomizing with any numbers except last number. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are right . I edited it in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?? Just, concatenate in the random value...

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
alert('http://test' + randomnumber + '.com/'); // or console.log()... just say'n.
```

Comment: It cannot solve this line . . 

document.write(&quot;<object data='http://test'+randomnumber+'.com/' height='100%' type='text/html' width='102%'/>&quot;);

Comment: Because you are mixing single a double quotes, try: `document.write('<object data="http://test' + randomnumber + '.com/" height="100%" type="text/html" width="102%"/>');` Concatenating in JS will ignore double quotes if single quotes are used to express the string first and vice versa. For more information, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10787418/1171790