# Change the value of javascript variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, quotes

I have javascript variable `var result` as following which has java variable that have JSON data like this

```
var result = <%=JsonData1%> ;
alert(result.toSource());
```

Above code similar to this code as showing on alert message

```
 var result= [{"year":"12","value":"6694"},{"year":"13","value":"50"},{"year":"08","value":"4776"},{"year":"09","value":"29006"},{"year":"10","value":"1751"}];
```

but I need to place a single quote on JSON data

```
'[{"year":"12","value":"6694"},{"year":"13","value":"50"},{"year":"08","value":"4776"},{"year":"09","value":"29006"},{"year":"10","value":"1751"}]'
```

and place it in new javascript variable like this

```
var json_pre =  result;
alert(json_pre);
```

but when I change my `result` data that placed in new `json_pre` variable as in this link [How to add single quote in the variable in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787393/how-to-add-single-quote-in-the-variable-in-javascript)

```
var json_pre =  "'" +result+ "'";
alert(json_pre.toSource());
```

then json data shows me like this on the alert message

```
'[{year:(new Date(-2208058200000)), value:6694}, {year:(new Date(-2207971800000)), value:50}, {year:(new Date(-2208403800000)), value:4776}, {year:(new Date(-2208317400000)), value:29006}, {year:(new Date(-2208231000000)), value:1751}]'
```

As I have tried every method that given me on that link.So anyone can help me in this?

Comment: My question would be *why* do you need to wrap that in single quotes?

Comment: I need that type of JSON further in code.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't think you do. `JSON.stringify(result)` is what you need, and it returns a JSON string. No need to wrap it in quotes, since it already is a string.

Comment: Adding server-side code is useless, we need to see the result, how it ends up in your browser's source view (press Ctrl+U). Anyway, did you try `alert(JSON.stringify(result));` right after setting `var result = <%=JsonData1%>;`? Edit: I did.

Comment: yeah it showing me same required data but it changes when I placed it in a new variable with single quotes and I need that type of json in the further code for the different purpose

Comment: I'll go ahead and say "no you don't". Even without seeing that code. I'm 99% sure now this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It sounds like you want do 1. receive JSON 2. change some of it 3. do something with the result. Can you post the actual problem?

Comment: okay I just want to know one thing is that code                                        var result_pre = "'" + JSON.stringify(result) + "'";                                        changes json into string format variable in javascript

Comment: Like I already told you `JSON.stringify()` returns a STRING. There is no need to add quotes. It is *already* a STRING: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/gspa4147/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166885/discussion-between-kunal-and-chris-g).

Comment: @ChrisG please check my requirement for this type of json in that discussion link

Answer (score 0):

`result` is not JSON, but a JavaScript object.

What you need to do is to `stringify` your object to JSON and then add the quotes:

```js
var result = [{"year":"12","value":"6694"},{"year":"13","value":"50"},{"year":"08","value":"4776"},{"year":"09","value":"29006"},{"year":"10","value":"1751"}];
var result_pre = "'" + JSON.stringify(result) + "'";
console.log(result_pre);
```

But it is questionable why you would even need that.

Comment: i am getting like this on alert message

Comment: '[{"year":"1900-01-11T18:30:00.000Z","value":6694},{"year":"1900-01-12T18:30:00.000Z","value":50},{"year":"1900-01-07T18:30:00.000Z","value":4776},{"year":"1900-01-08T18:30:00.000Z","value":29006},{"year":"1900-01-09T18:30:00.000Z","value":1751}]'

Comment: @kunal That is not possible with the code I provided. There must be something else in your code that does it, but you did not show your code.

Comment: @kunal As I already said "That is not possible with the code I provided". Your code or template engine obviously changes the string and in addition there is no (standard) `toSource` function on strings.

Comment: okay I just want to know one thing, is that code                                      var result_pre = "'" + JSON.stringify(result) + "'";                           changes json into string format variable in javascript

Comment: @kunal That line takes an *object* and *stringifies* it to *JSON*, then it adds single quotes. `result_pre` is a string containing single quotes containing JSON. `result_pre` itself is not JSON, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166886/discussion-between-kunal-and-str).

Comment: please check my requirement for this type of json in that discussion link

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the single quotes does not make an object a string. When you are trying to store it in a variable I guess you are making the same mistake again.

when you do this

```
a={"key":"value"}
b="'" + a + "'";
```

You get a string representation for consoles, if you want a JSON string to be stored in a variable you need to do this

```
var json = JSON.stringify(result);
alert(json);
```

You don't need quotes for that.

Comment: This is a duplicate of str's answer.

Comment: Nobody downvoted you for that answer. Comments are here also to guide other users to the best answer, don't take them personnally. You can indeed delete it as it brings nothing new, or just let it here as it won't harm anybody