# How can I add additional single quotes to string in javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a string inside `<script></script>` which has a variable.

```
var buildurl = response.show.url;
var connectHtml = '<button class="form_button" id="connectButton" onclick="window.location='+buildurl+'">Connect</button>'
$('#someElement').html(connectHtml);
```

When I inspect the element, I see the url built but without the single quotes (''). So when I click on the button, it does not navigate to the url.
How can I add the '' to get

> onclick="window.location=**'**https://something.com/admin/one/two/123/456**'**"
>   ?

```
<button class="form_button" id="connectButton" onclick="window.location=https://something.com/admin/one/two/123/456">Connect</button>
```

Comment: Why not just make a function that redirects and then call that onclick?

Comment: @FunkDoc Even if I were to move the "window.location" inside a function, I would still face the issue of missing single quotes. I am not able to add the quotes to the string using a concatenation operator.

Comment: Trying to find a good duplicate (I imagine there is one), but in the meantime, `onclick="window.location=\''+buildurl+'\'"`

Comment: @PatrickQ  Here's another way I found - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787393/how-to-add-single-quote-in-the-variable-in-javascript . thanks!

Comment: Which ever quotes you're using as delimiter for your string have to be escaped when you want to use them in that same string.

Comment: @user3344978 Yeah, just got to that one.  Think I might settle on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals and not worry about apostrophes and quotes:

```
`<button class="form_button" id="connectButton" onclick="window.location='${buildurl}'">Connect</button>`
```

Comment: @PatrickQ good point, thank you. It's fixed now.